# initializing a global char array in objective c

Tags: objective-c, array-initialization

my class

```
          @interface appViewController : UIViewController {
                      ...
                      char Sequence[5][102];
                      ... 
                     }
```

i have 5 sets of characters having 102 characters each, i want to assign them to each row of the  array Sequence[ ][ ].

if it was C i would do something like

```
         char Sequence[5][102]={{...},{...},{...},{...},{...}}
```

but how to do it in Objective C as i cant just assign any values when i declare this array inside the class

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in the constructor (usually `-init` or `-initWithFrame:` or similar). You cannot do this in the `@interface` directly, like this:

```
- (id)init {
  if (self = [super init]) {
    Sequence[0][0] = 0x00;
    Sequence[0][1] = 0x01;
    Sequence[0][2] = 0x02;
    Sequence[0][3] = 0x03;
    // etc…
  }
  return self;
}
```

If you have a giant amount of items (5 * 102 = 510), you could store them in a plist and read it at runtime.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a sample initialization method. Please note that you must initialize your object like `[[myClass alloc] init]`. Also note that you must keep the `@interface` like in your question (`char Sequence[5][102];`).

Comment: A plist ?? can you direct me to some online resources to know about plist cuz i m totally new to this technology so i dont have any idea about plist.